# Error in reading value from SV in C++ function using DPI

Tags: c++, system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I am trying to pass a string from SV to C++ function but the value is not getting passed properly to C++ function

Code in SV side:

```
    import "DPI" function string mainsha(string str);
    class scoreboard ;
     string text_i_cplus;
     string text_o_cplus; 
    text_i_cplus="abc";
    text_o_cplus=mainsha(text_i_cplus);
```

That's how I am sending value to C++ . At the C++ side I am taking value as:

```
    extern "C" string mainsha(string input)
 {

    string output1 = sha256(input);

    cout << "sha256('"<< input << "'):" << output1 << endl;
   return output1;
 }
```

I am getting correct output when I running the C++ prog alone. But at the console I am getting the following output:

> sha256(''):e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DPI in current SystemVerilog standard only supports the C language, not C++. In fact you should be using `import "DPI-C"`. in C++, `string` is a class and C only has arrays of `char`

```
  extern "C" const char * mainsha(const char * input)
 {

    string output1 = sha256(input); // not sure if you need a cast here

    cout << "sha256('"<< input << "'):" << output1 << endl;
   return output1.c_str();
 }
```

If you are using Modelsim/Questa, there is a -dpiheader switch that you can use that automatically generates the DPI prototypes for you and you can include that file when you compile your C++ code. That way you will get a compiler error if there is a mismatch and not have to debug run-time behaviors.

Comment: I read your comment about current SV standard only support the C language not C++  in some other post too. But I was going through the book "SystemVerilog for Verification :A Guide to Learning the Testbench
Language Features- Second Edition " where there is a section called "Connecting to C++" which states that we can use C++.Is that just a theory/future implemention? Also, I am using VCS.

Comment: You can use C++, you just have to stick with C compatible types in the interface. It's the same as if you are connecting C code to C++.